# Sending Email Reminder (while loop)

Tags: php, loops, email, while-loop, reminders

I'm testing this code out. I assigned two reminders with test date and time values. Two reminders should be sent out to two different people. However when I run it, one will  get an email containing their reminder, while the other person receives an email **containing both his and the other reminder in the body of the email**

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

```
 <?
date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles"); 
//$trigger_date = date('h:i \P\S\T');
//$trigger_time = date('h:i A');

//test date and time
$trigger_date = date('Y-m-d');
$trigger_time = date('04:51');


$your_reminder = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM reminders WHERE reminder_date = '$trigger_date' AND reminder_time = '$trigger_time'");
$todaydate =  date("Y-m-d");
$row = $your_reminder->num_rows;
if ($row == 0 ){
    echo "Nothing to Send</div>";
    } else {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($your_reminder))
    {   $reminder_owner = $row["reminder_owner"];
        //echo $reminder_owner;
        //echo "<br>Title:".$row["reminder_title"];
        $send_owner = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='$reminder_owner'");
        $row_owner = mysqli_fetch_array($send_owner,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $email = $row_owner["admin_email"];
        $headers = 'From: TeamInfoPage';
        $email_subject ="Reminder Test: ".$row["reminder_title"];
        $reminder_details .= "Hi ".$row_owner["admin_fn"]."\n";
        $reminder_details .= "Event: ".$row["reminder_title"]."\n";
        //          $reminder_details .= $row["tasks_notes"]."\n\n";
        //Send out Reminder mail
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        @mail($email, $email_subject, $reminder_details, $headers);

    }
echo "Success";}
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset the `reminder_details` to blank between loop iterations.

Simply change these lines:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($your_reminder))
{   $reminder_owner = $row["reminder_owner"];
    //echo $reminder_owner;
```

To this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($your_reminder))
{   $reminder_owner = $row["reminder_owner"];
    $reminder_details = "";
    //echo $reminder_owner;
```

Answer (score 1):

Plz reset the value of reminder_details in the loop for each mail..

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: $reminder_details ="";             reminder_details .= "Hi ".$row_owner["admin_fn"]."\n";